# Velocity 2 won't set property

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss, velocity

I am trying to upgrade a project from Spring 3 to Spring 5.0.5. I updated velocity with this new initialization that I wrote:

```
private static void initVelocity() throws VelocityException, IOException{
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath"); 
    props.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());

    Velocity.init( props );
}
```

I am using the follow dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity-engine-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But for a strange reason when I do `Velocity.getProperty( "classpath.resource.loader.class");` I get a `null`, and I am getting a `NullPointerException` when I try to get a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really well-versed in Velocity, but we typically create a new `VelocityEngine` instance. You'd get that property from the particular instance instead of the Velocity object itself. See the following code:

```
Properties props = new Properties()
props.put("classpath.resource.loader.class", 
          ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
props.put(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
VelocityEngine engine = new VelocityEngine(props);
```

Now get the loader via

```
engine.getProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class");
```

Comment: Thx to your proposal i found the problem, for a dependency of a dependency jboss got in the project folder Velocity 1.6 and Velocity 2.0 and it was using the older one. I deleted the old one (i rewrote code as you said) and everything is work now, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Velocity was [removed from Spring 5](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13795) ( [deprecated in spring 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38128166/why-velocity-support-is-deprecated-in-spring-4-3))

> For Spring 5, we are strategically moving away from traditional template-based web views in general. Even just for that reason alone, we are not going to introduce support for any new template engine generations but rather focus on other areas (Jackson integration, JavaScript templates, etc). FWIW, we are going to keep supporting FreeMarker as a sort of reference - in classic Servlet MVC as well as Spring's new reactive web support -, including our generic base classes for template-based views which other support classes may derive from (like the Velocity 1.x based view classes do right now).

There's a comment to wait/request velocity 2 support

> As mentioned above, any stakeholders there, please ask the Velocity team to ship Spring adapters for Velocity 2.0 themselves

And here's some [tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42109387/velocity-with-springboot-1-5-x) for continue using velocity

> remove spring.velocity.properties:
>
> Add the properties created the Bean:
>
> ```
> @Bean
> VelocityEngine velocityEngine(){
>     Properties properties = new Properties();
>     properties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/application.properties"));
>     return new VelocityEngine(properties);
> }
> ```

Comment: I know about Velocity removal on Spring 5, but they released 2.0 to grown compatibility with new Spring. As i commented on @Matt reply, the problem was caused by two versions of Velocity included on lib folder, probabily a dependency needed velocity. Thank you for your help anyway