# Spring boot 2 issue with velocity, lombok and annotation processor

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We have a spring boot application where we have used
java 8,
spring boot 1,
velocity 1.7,
lombok etc.
We are generating classes from custom annoations using domain annotation processor(javax.annoation.processing.*) at compile time. We use .vm files here.

But when we upgrade the spring boot from spring boot 1 to spring boot 2, the classes are not getting generated.
So is spring boot 2 not supporting velocity or reason is something else?

Comment: Velocity support was dropped see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50218020/velocity-2-wont-set-property/50226604#50226604

Comment: Can i get any response from spring people from